# Unable to open PHP script files, even though I own them and have permissions

Tags: bash, selinux, rhel8, compliance

I'm using RHEL 8, and I have run into a crazy problem.  My user account is unable to open PHP files.

If I have a file, owned by my user, and readable by my user, and I add `<?php` as the first line, I'm suddenly unable to open, edit, or view the file, even though I have not otherwise changed my permissions.  It tells me:  `cat: test.txt: Operation not permitted`

If I look at the file using `file`, I see the file reported as `PHP Script` once I add the above line.

It doesn't appear to be an SELinux problem, since `setenforce 0` doesn't change the behavior, and `audit2allow` doesn't see anything.

It's possible this is happening to all script files, but on this server, I only need to use PHP scripts.  Help!

Comment: Can you show the output of `ls -lah <php_file>`, and `stat --format='%a %n' <php_file>` where <php_file> is one of the affected files?

Comment: `-rw-r-----. 1 nick nick 6.2k Apr 17 15:54 test.txt` and `640 test.txt`.  Context is `unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0`. `lsattr` only works with sudo, and shows `-------------------- test.txt`.

Comment: awesome! both `cat` and `file` read the file, at least beginning, so not exactly the permissions. something weird with terminal formatting maybe? next i would check if problem is present for `root` account, then different user account and then look at syscalls with `strace cat test.txt`. strace will produce a lot of output, but should name failed syscall somewhere

Comment: The failed syscall is: `openat(AT_FDCWD, "test.txt", O_RDONLY) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)`  When I try with a file that does not have the `<?php` header, that syscall returns successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found my answer.

As part of a security audit on our web-host servers, the auditor recommended to the administrator that we follow STIG and NIST compliance standards on the servers.  We didn't strictly need to follow these standards, but they are highly respected best practices for hardening machines, so it seemed like a worthy goal.

During testing of the standards, no issues were discovered, and the standards were deployed on the servers.

As it turns out `fapolicyd` is installed as part of these standards, and one of its default policies is to block user access to program files.  This didn't impact the web application, but only user editing of those files.

Disabling `fapolicyd` service allowed the user to edit files.  As needed, policies can be added to allow this access all the time.

For more info: http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/fapolicyd/index.html